# HTML5 Window Pane Code

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking for a specific bit of code, probably HTML5 or JQuery. Anyone can point me in the direction of a tut for this?

I want to have a selection of thumbnails. When clicked, a pane should open up on the page. Like a pop-up. but not in a separate browser window. I just want a white box with a thin black outline and a dropshadow to appear that I can fill with content.

Help?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to create a modal window. Lightbox is pretty much the standard way of doing this. It might be more than you need but it works everywhere. http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/).

It's easy to set up, extensible, and support image gallery, ajax, video, etc...

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a modal. A great jQuery plugin for this is Simple Modal.

http://simplemodal.plasm.it/